# how to terminate a process which is run with sudo? Ctrl+C do it, but not kill

Tags: linux, bash, shell

At my company, some commands are allowed to run with sudo, such as tcpdump. Others not.

I expect run tcpdump for a while, and then stop it.
When I run tcpdump, and I could abort that with Ctrl+C

I wrote a shell script like this -

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo tcpdump -ieth1 -w ~/dump.bin
sleep 5
kill -2 $!
```

it doesn't really work. The process of tcpdump is run as root, and current user is a normal account.

My question is: is there any way to do the equivalent of ctrl c in bash script?.

EDIT:

ps:As my company's security policy, I cannot run kill as root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the `-Z` option to `tcpdump`.  It instructs tcpdump to drop root privileges and run as the user specified in the argument.

```
sudo tcpdump -Z $USER -ieth1 -w ~/dump.bin
```

Now try killing that process.

Answer (score 5):

Simply run `kill` through `sudo` as well:

```
sudo kill -2 $!
```

This way the `kill` process will have the privilege to send signals to a process that runs as root.

Comment: Thanks Blagovest, I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear!  For the security policy at my company, I cann't run kill as root, and cann't add any command into sudo config file.

Comment: It's dangerous to allow to kill any process to a non-prvileged user.

Answer (score 2):

For programs that don't have special switches like `-Z` and in case you can alter sudoers file, this is a solution:

```
sudo myprogram &
sleep 5
sudo pkill myprogram
```

All I have to do is to allow to run `pkill myprogram` passwordless by using `visudo` and adding this line:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/pkill myprogram
```

This is less dangerous that lo let sudo kill any program.

Answer (score 1):

The [timeout](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/timeout.1.php) command also terminates a program after so long. `sudo timeout 5 tcpdump -ieth1 -w ~/dump.bin` should accomplish the same thing as the script.

Comment: timeout command should be added into sudo config file first.I cann't do that, due to company's security policy.

Comment: You link is dead: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo tcpdump -ieth1 -w ~/dump.bin
```

will block your script, you need to put it into the background:

```
sudo tcpdump -ieth1 -w ~/dump.bin &
```

.

This and the [answer from Blagovest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7269975/) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo tcpdump -Z root -w ~/dump.bin -n -i eth0 -G 300 -W 1
```

G - Timeout Seconds (After timeout period the comman gets killed automatically)
Z - drop root and runs as user privilege 
W - Number files to be saved (as a splitted file)